# When we send FCM sometimes image is not shown in notification

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send notifications to my Android app. However, sometimes the images are not showing up in the notifications, especially when the app is in the background or terminated. I have checked that the image format and size are correct, and the URL is accessible. I am not sure what else could be causing this issue.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue with FCM notifications not showing images when the app is in the background or terminated? If so, what was the solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

We have taken the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

Checked the image size and format: We ensured that the image is in a supported format, and the size is not too large.

Checked network and connectivity: We made sure that the user's network connection is stable and fast enough to download the image.

Checked client-side settings: We checked if the user has enabled the app to display images in notifications. Also, we verified that the app does not have any restrictions on displaying images.

Checked Firebase configuration: We verified that Firebase settings are correctly configured, and the notification payload includes the correct image URL.

Comment: which android version do you have?

Comment: I have tested in Android 10,11,12 & 13 and I found this issue in each version

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.